# Nginx Solution for AWS Amazon ELB Health Checks - return 200 without IF

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have the following code that is working on Nginx to keep the AWS ELB healthcheck happy.

```
map $http_user_agent $ignore {
  default 0;
  "ELB-HealthChecker/1.0" 1;
}

server {
  location / {
    if ($ignore) {
      access_log off;
      return 200;
    }
  }
}
```

I know the 'IF' is best avoided with Nginx and I wanted to ask if someone would know how to recode this without the 'if'?

thankyou

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things. Just point your ELB health checks at a special URL just for them.

```
server {
  location /elb-status {
    access_log off;
    return 200;
  }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for you reply... can you explain a touch more... currently in the ELB health check I'm pointing it at /index.html. Do you mean point the health checks at say '/elb-status' and the add the above server block? is that it? does the /elb-status url need to exist? thx again

Comment: worked perfectly when I put /elb-status in the ELB and added the server block above - thankyou so much!!! greatly apprecated

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @ceejayoz, that was a clever solution. I spun up an instance that is getting no outside traffic, and one the elb status checks are taken care of, this starts to show up in the log, I think it is the ELB latency checks, any ideas there?


10.244.162.24 - - [26/Dec/2013:06:04:18 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"

Comment: Hmm, I'm gettting `"/usr/share/nginx/html/elb-status" failed (2: No such file or directory)`... any idea why this could be?

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall If you do `curl -I http://localhost/elb-status` from the server, does it give you a 200?

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall i have seen the same issue and an nginx restart seems to fix, but this is obviously no good when we want to auto scale our instances

Comment: Neat solution. 

Comment: Working fine. Does the access log of nginx shows this request ? Not showing up for me.

Comment: @SandeepBalagopal See that `access_log off` line?

Comment: Thank you. Such a simple solution

Answer (score 33):

Just to improve on the above answer, which is correct. The following works great:

```
location /elb-status {
    access_log off;
    return 200 'A-OK!';
    # because default content-type is application/octet-stream,
    # browser will offer to "save the file"...
    # the next line allows you to see it in the browser so you can test 
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Update: If the user agent validation is necessary,

```
set $block 1;

# Allow only the *.example.com hosts. 
if ($host ~* '^[a-z0-9]*\.example\.com$') {
   set $block 0;
}

# Allow all the ELB health check agents.
if ($http_user_agent ~* '^ELB-HealthChecker\/.*$') { 
  set $block 0;
}

if ($block = 1) { # block invalid requests
  return 444;
}

# Health check url
location /health {
  return 200 'OK';
  add_header Content-Type text/plain;
}
```