# Nginx container health-check for AWS-ALB

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-alb

I need to have a health-check path for ALB setup that points to a server which has docker container Nginx. I do not have access inside the EC2 server to add a file there. I can just add something in Docker-Container

I have tried the following solution however it doesn't work for me because I have another block in my config file that prevents it I guess.

[Nginx Solution for AWS Amazon ELB Health Checks - return 200 without IF](https://serverfault.com/questions/518220/nginx-solution-for-aws-amazon-elb-health-checks-return-200-without-if)

My config file looks like below:

```
server 
{    
   listen      443 ssl http2;
   server_name     server-test.com;
   access_log  /var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log;
   error_log   /var/log/nginx/nginx.error.log;
   ssl    on;
   ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
   ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
   ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256';
   ssl_session_timeout 1d;
   ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_tickets off;

   location /
   {
      proxy_pass         http://server-test.io:5015/;
      proxy_redirect     off;

      ##proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

      client_max_body_size       10m;
      client_body_buffer_size    128k;

      proxy_connect_timeout      90;
      proxy_send_timeout         90;
      proxy_read_timeout         90;

      proxy_buffer_size          4k;
      proxy_buffers              4 32k;
      proxy_busy_buffers_size    64k;
      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
   }
 }
...
...
...

# Health check url
server {
  location /elb-status {
    access_log off;
    return 200 'A-OK!';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }
}
# Redirect non-existing domains to 404
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 404;
}
server {
  server_name _;
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
  return 404;
}
```

When I open the server with path /elb-status, it gives me 404 Not Found. And also the status of server under LoadBalancer is unhealty. I think it's because of block: "Redirect non-existing domains" but I need to have that block as well.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edited based on Andy reply:**

[image: ALB-HealthCheck]

[image: ALB-Targer]

[image: Nginx Config File in Docker Container]

The Nginx container uses both ports 80 and 443, I've set up the Target group for the servers, which include Nginx docker container, based on these ports but still the servers health check is Unhealthy.

Is there something that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2):

How about running the `server` block containing `location /elb-status` on another port?

When creating the ALB, there is a `Advanced health check settings` dropdown. In these settings you can override the health check port. You can set the port to something like `8080` and then your `server` becomes:

```
server {
  listen 8080;
  location /elb-status {
    access_log off;
    return 200 'A-OK!';
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
  }
}
```

There is no need for virtual host based routing for health checks in this setup. Port `8080` would be dedicated to only the health check.

Don't forget to open the appropriate port in your security group between the ALB and EC2 instances if you choose to go this route.

Comment: To follow on from this: You second server stanza is picking up everything as the default. 
Server blocks are not chosen based on the content of their locations.

Comment: Thanks Andy but adding listen 8080 didn't fix the problem.

Comment: @ReverendTim yes that's because I want to redirect all unknown servers no matter what location it is. But how it can work with that healthcheck block ?

Comment: @sarah - to respond to your comment to andy: you will need to change your ELB Health check (from the aws console) to point to port 8080, and obviously make sure that port 8080 is open on your security group to the EC2 instance. and the other comment: having a default server is fine, but you need to shortcircuit the health check to another port so that it's not picked up by your default. Andy's solution will work perfectly - i know because that's how mine works ;)

Comment: @ReverendTim thanks for the comment. I actually did what Andy told but it doesn't work for me. Please check the edited question and let me know why I'm missing

Comment: From inside the EC2 serves can you `curl -v localhost:8080/elb-status` to confirm the nginx part is correct?

Comment: @AndyShinn I don't have access inside the EC2 server. Because it has been built and managed by [https://cloud.docker.com ] I can just see inside the docker container.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The easiest and cleanest solution(IMHO), would be to add a default server block to handle both health checks and unknown domains:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  # Catch all requests with an invalid HOST header
  location / {
    return 444;
  }

  # Health check endpoint
  location /ping { # or whatever endpoint you are using
    access_log off;
    return 200 "pong!";
  }
}
```